# HttpSession does not work

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

I have following code segment in my servlet. Here, for some reason, I can not hold the session for the same user after creation of one session.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter writer =  response.getWriter();
String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

if (userName != "" && userName != null) {
    session.setAttribute("savedUserName", userName);
}

writer.println("Request parameter has user name as : " + userName + "<br />");
writer.println("Request session has user name as : " + (String) session.getAttribute("savedUserName") + "<br />");
    }
```

Comment: You should accept answers to your earlier questions for people to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

On what basis are you implying that the session is not working? The only scenario that might not work is when you have not supplied `userName` in which case the it will be `null` and session will never be created as your below code is testing the condition in wrong order and **the equality check should use equals() and not !=**

```
if (userName != "" && userName != null) {
    session.setAttribute("savedUserName", userName);
}
```

It should be changed to

```
if (userName != null && !userName.equals("")) {
    session.setAttribute("savedUserName", userName);
}
```

Comment: @Shahjalal what was the issue? is it related to the code you posted?